# Obtain a complete file list of a directory structure and output in a text file but on a single line not many

Tags: batch-file, directory

I am currently using this batch script. I select the files I want and drop them over the bat file which then creates a list of the files I want in 1 line (fulllist.txt). Great!!
However, it doesn't support sub directories which I need it to. I want a complete list of files with directory structure intact. How can I do this?
 Batch:

```
@echo off
setlocal

:loop
  if [%1]==[] goto end
  set arg=%arg% "%~nx1"
  shift
  goto loop

:end
echo %arg% >fulllist.txt
pause
```

Comment: Do not use any argument modifiers. Just use %1

Comment: Sorry I don't follow??. If I drag the root folder over my batch I just get the name of the root folder, no content

Comment: why not just `>fullist.txt echo %*`?